# How to resize grey area at top of Python IDLE editor window

Tags: python-3.x, python-idle

Beginner question - using IDLE w/ Python version 3.3 under Windows 7.  There is a grey bar at the top of the editor window showing the current indent level (I tried but apparently don't have enough stackOverflow reputation points to show an image of it).

I find this area to be useful but sometimes my code is indented to more levels than can be displayed in the three lines shown in the grey area.  Is it possible to resize this area?  It would be great if it could resize automatically based on the current indent level.

I'm not even sure what this area is called but I don't see any configureIDLE options that seem to refer to it.

Answer (score 1):

The feature you are referring to, is 'Code Context'.

You can select 'Options', and un-tick 'Code Context' option to remove this.

As far as I am aware, there is no user-selectable option that allows you to resize it, but I hope I am wrong or that they include that feature.

Comment: In Aug 2014, we added `Configure Extensions` to the `Options` menu.  It is part of all releases since then.  For code context, one can set the number of lines.  (I believe this was possible before by hand-editing <HOMEDIR>/.idlerc/config-extensions.cfg, but this is error prone.)  In the future, I would like to make code context resize itself as needed.